# Non trivial solution of ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y$ be a non trivial solution of the ODE $y^{"}-q(x)y=0$, where $q(x)$ is positive monotonically  increasing and continuous function of $x$. How to prove that $y$ and $y'$ both tend to $\infty$ as x tends to $\infty$. I have no idea about it . How to start?

Comment: Please give me some hint...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Convert the 2nd Order ODE into a 1st order System of ODE.

Set $ u = y$ and $ v = y'$.

Then $u' = y' = v$ and $v' = y'' = q(x).y = q(x).u$.

Now form the system by

$[u',v']^T = A(x).[u,v]^T$ where A(x) is a $2x2$ matrix. Now analyse the eigenvalues of A(x). You will find an eigenvalue with positive real part.

Comment: How your concept is related to tendency of function?

Comment: Solutions of the vector $[y, y']^T$ is related to the eigenvalues of the matrix A.